# Loop through the array containing collection of another array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get fetch the value of date and courseName, but instead I'm getting these error exception.

**loop:**

```
array:2 [▼
 0 => Collection {#284 ▼
#items: array:3 [▼
  0 => {#277 ▼
    +"date": "2018"
  }
  1 => {#279 ▶}
  4 => {#282 ▶}``
 ]
 }
 1 => Collection {#283 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
   0 => {#280 ▼
     +"id": 1
     +"courseName": "newc1"
     }
  1 => {#271 ▶}
  ]
  }
  ]


 //tried these
  @foreach ($result as $key=> $value)
                    @foreach ($value as $val)
                        {{$val->date}}

                    @endforeach

                @endforeach 

      //controller
        $data = array();
        $date = db::table('students')->select('date')->get()->unique();
        $course = db::table('courses')->select('id', 'courseName')->get();
        array_push($data, $date, $course);
```

Needed to loop through these. Instead got
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined property: stdClass::$date

Answer (score 0):

You have to control the db result if it's okey on date select also for laravel use distinct() and get must be at the end before it

```
    //This
    $date = db::table('students')->select('date')->get()->unique();
    //To This
    $date = db::table('students')->select('date')->distinct()->get();

    if(!$date)
      return $this->response;
      //or
      return false;
```

//Update

```
$course = DB::table('students')
            ->select('id','courseName', 'courses')
            ->groupBy('courses')//What ever you want to uniqe
            ->get();
```

For Return View Example you have to change for yourself

```
return $this->responseWithView("index //PAGE","success", ['courses' => $course,'anything' => $youwant]);
```

Comment: i used distinct() but I am getting the same error. Actually I need to get all the data from date column of students and id and courseName column of courses on a single view page with out using eloquent  as far as possible. If there is any way possible.. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Check update if still gives error can you share more data about it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish by having these collections together in one array, but here is one way to solve it:

I noticed that you are inserting collections with different attributes into an array.

```php
$date = db::table('students')->select('date')->get()->unique();
```

So each item will have a `date` property

In the next query you select different columns:

```php
$course = db::table('courses')->select('id', 'courseName')->get();
```

Here each item will have an `id` and `courseName` property

As you can see you are holding different items in the same array.
So you need to check if the `date` attribute exists.

```
@foreach ($result as $key=> $value)
    @foreach ($value as $val)

        @if(isset($val->date))
            {{$val->date}}
        @endif

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am new to this laravel and actually I need to get all the data from date column of students and id and courseName column of courses on a single view page with out using eloquent  as far as possible. If there is any way .. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps you can just make the HTML of how you want your page to look like on https://jsbin.com so I can see what you mean